# "Solution for business" or "Solution for businesses"

Tags: grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I'm wondering which slogan for a business is more correct:

> "Solution for business" or "Solution for businesses"?

For example, in a company that created an innovative security product:

> "Security solution for business" or "Security solution for
>   businesses"?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to my English-Business-Exam in 2015, there is no use of
"businesses". You might say, "companies" or "solutions for your business".

Businesses, definitely no. Maybe in former times.

Comment: I've seen you added the word "your" and used the plural "solutions". Would it be still correct like I wrote above: "Security solution for business"?

Comment: Are you offering different products or services ? Then, "solutions" would imply that to your customer. If you are offering a speacial product, I would offer this as: "Product A" - The solution for your business.

Comment: "Security solutions for your business" can be fine, but Is it for example:
helmets, alarmsystems, server-security,  plant-security, ect.... ?